# Bot reacts with nitro emojis that I don't have

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js, bots

node version 13

So can I make the bot reacts to message with nitro emojis that I don't have?if yup how

Here is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = (client) => {
    const suggestionChannel = client.channels.cache.get('898834097181437963') // Channel For Suggestion
    client.on('message', message => {
        if(message.channel === suggestionChannel) {
            if(message.author.bot) return // Does not Delete BOTs Messages
            message.delete() // Delete Original Message Sent By User

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#000000')
            .setTitle(`${message.author.tag} suggested something!`,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
            .setDescription(`**${message.content}**`)
            .setFooter('Vote if you agree/disagree!')
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]}).then(message => { // Reactions
                message.react('emoji1') // Change Emoji
                message.react('emoji2') // Change Emoji
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want to get animated emoji id so you can use it to react like with non-animated one, so:

1. Open developer tools in Chrome
2. Open the window with emoji, scroll emoji into view
3. Enter element selector mode
4. Click on the emoji
5. Developer tools window should highlight an element that starts with `<li role`
6. Element should have a drop-down arrow to the left of it, click on it to reveal its code
7. You should now see `<img...` element. It should have a `src="link"` text. Right click on url and "Cipy link address".
8. You will get something like:
   `https://cdn.discord.com/emojis/emoji_id.png?v=1` Now you only need to copy this id and when you have both name and id use:
   `message.react('<:emoji_name:emoji_id>')` but if your emoji is `.gif` you have to use `message.react('<a:emojiname:emojiid>')` instead

Comment: Yup, I know that but I mean Nitro emojis, not the normal one.

Comment: You forget to handle if it's not `.png` but `.gif`, in that case @Asuka , use `message.react('<a:emojiname:emojiid>'). Adding the `a` for `animated` before `:` will make the emoji animate as it should

Comment: Where is the window with emoji?